# Initialize Redux Toolkit store via url params on Next 12+ SSR

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I am pretty new with NextJS (12) and I am creating an ecommerce website in which I have some UI filters; I am using getServerSideProps to fetch data since I need the site to be SEO compliant.

When a user clicks on the filters, I am updating the global state and triggering next/router that fetches fresh data and populate the page simply passing query params to the url. Everything seems to work pretty well.

When a user lands on the site with active filters (via url query params), I am populating the page with correct data via getServerSideProps (parsing url query params), but now I should also enrich Redux state with the active filters, to show the correct UI.

Is there any way to initialize Redux Toolkit store via url params on page load (SSR)?

I know I am not posting any code here, but I need to know if using Redux Toolkit in this scenario could be overkill in the first place, and if there's any way to achieve what I need without over complicated sync libraries.

Thank you very much

Comment: May I ask you why do you need a state manager in this scenario?

Comment: @bitfella since the UI is scattered across many components, sometimes I need to know when a particular filter is active to do stuff on another one that could be very far from the first. Do you think this could be accomplished in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this could help you and even if this could be a good practice or an anti-pattern instead, but - since I suppose that you've passed your store to the app there - why don't you just grab your query params via useRouter in the _app, compose the actual store in there with query string and then pass it to the store provider?

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { Provider as StoreProvider } from 'react-redux';

import store from '../store';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  const { query } = useRouter();
  const realStore = doSomethingWithQueryAndReturnRealStore(store, query);

  return (
    <StoreProvider store={realStore}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </StoreProvider>
  );
};
```

Keep in mind that I haven't tested it, it's just an assumption :)